# How to replace specific rows based on conditions of another dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, bioinformatics

I have have 2 genetic datasets which look like:

dataset1:

```
ID          Chr Ref Alt
1:10000476  NA  NA  NA
1:10081736  NA  NA  NA
1:100829685 NA  NA  NA
1:100829720 NA  NA  NA
10:1008338  NA  NA  NA
```

dataset2:

```
ID          Chr Ref Alt
1:10000476  1   A   T
1:10081736  1   C   G
2:133248    2   A   T
3:300829720 3   A   T
10:1008338  10  A   T
```

I am trying to replace any NA's in dataset 1 with the data from dataset 2 if they have the same ID

Trying to output:

```
ID          Chr Ref Alt
1:10000476  1   A   T
1:10081736  1   C   G
1:100829685 NA  NA  NA
1:100829720 NA  NA  NA
10:1008338  10  A   T

#first 2 rows have their NAs replaced with the data in the 2nd dataset, as the IDs match
```

I have a biology background, so haven't been sure where to start with this, my datasets also have many more columns. So far I have tried using `merge(df1, df2, by='ID', all.x=TRUE)`, but this is creating 2 versions of the columns with '.x' and '.y' - it looks like I could just take the columns with '.y' but I'm not sure why this is appearing in the first place and can't find information to know if I can trust it. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
#dataset1
dput(df1)
structure(list(ID = c("1:10000476", "1:10081736", "1:100829685", 
"1:100829720", "1:100833868"), Chr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Ref = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Alt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

#dataset2
dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = c("1:10000476", "1:10081736", "2:133248", 
"3:300829720", "4:5543348"), Chr = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Ref = c("A", 
"C", "A", "A", "A"), Alt = c("T", "G", "T", "T", "T")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your "input data" is not the same as shown in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `dplyr` would be

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "ID", suffix = c("_to_be_removed", "")) %>% 
  select(-contains("_to_be_removed"))
```

Output

```
#            ID Chr  Ref  Alt
# 1  1:10000476   1    A    T
# 2  1:10081736   1    C    G
# 3 1:100829685  NA <NA> <NA>
# 4 1:100829720  NA <NA> <NA>
# 5 1:100833868  NA <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
library(data.table)
df1[, c("Chr", "Ref", "Alt") := df2[.SD, on = "ID", .(Chr, Ref, Alt)]]
df1

            ID Chr  Ref  Alt
1:  1:10000476   1    A    T
2:  1:10081736   1    C    G
3: 1:100829685  NA <NA> <NA>
4: 1:100829720  NA <NA> <NA>
5: 1:100833868  NA <NA> <NA>
```